# Question on solvability of surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ being expressed as graph of a function locally.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the following set:

$$S := \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2-4x+y^4+4y^3+6y^2+4y-z^4 = \alpha \}$$

The question asks to  determine the value(s) of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $S$ is locally the graph of a $C^{\infty}$ function (of 2 variables). Doing this would require me to find the critical point of the stated expression, after finding this expression I would then plug this critical point back into my expression and I would obtain a value for $\alpha$. The reason this works is because the critical point is a singularity in my set, which is a surface.

Now the Implicit function theorem states that if I have a point $(a,b,c) \in S$ such that $F(a,b,c) = 0$ then I can express my surface near the point $(a,b,c)$ as the graph of a $C^{1}$ function i.e $z= f(x,y), y = f(x,z), x = f(y,z)$ (dependent on the specific results).

So in the set that I have above I only have the critical point that I solved for, but locally at this point I specifically cannot express my set as the graph of $C^{1}$ function.

I have two questions:

1) Is this the right way of thinking about this scenario?

2) If I did want to express my set as the graph of a function that would mean I have to somehow find some point $(a,b,c) \in S$ that would satisfy my expression.  Visually I am fortunate enough to be able to see that the surface is smooth everywhere else except at the critical point as shown below. But say I didn't have the luxury of knowing what this visually looked like, are there any techniques to find said points or is it just a free for all?

[image]

Comment: "The question asks to determine the values of $\alpha$ for a particular $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$". I'm not sure I understand your question (it seems like an incomplete sentence). Do you perhaps mean "determine the value(s) of $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $S$ is locally the graph of a $C^{\infty}$ function (of $2$ variables)"?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, that is what I was thinking as well because I just copied it verbatim from the professor's website. But based on what we are studying that would seem correct.

Comment: ok then what did you find as the "good" values of $\alpha$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I didn't actually perform the procedure to find the $\alpha$ explicitly because I understand that part. I was attempting to expand from that idea.

Comment: @peek-a-boo. After attempting to solve it quickly I got two of the coordinates, the $y$ coordinate requires solving a cubic function: Critical point: $(2, -1, 0)$....The question though remains with respect to finding a graph of the surface somewhere else locally.

Comment: The ? is $-1$, because that equation for $y$ can be factored as $4(y+1)^3$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo TRUUUEEE...I didin't observe that until now...

Comment: For notation sake, denote that function as $f$ and let $S_{\alpha} = f^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$. At the point $(2,-1,0)$, we have $f(2,-1,0) = 5$ (if I didn't mess up). Now, (I'm pretty sure that) although on the whole of $\Bbb{R}^3$, $(2,-1,0)$ is the only point where the matrix $f'$ vanishes, I think this is enough to make the entire level set $S_5 = f^{-1}(\{5\})$ bad.

Comment: And when I say $S_5$ is a "bad" level set, I mean that it is possibe to have several points $p_1, \dots, p_k \in S_5$ for which it is not possible to locally describe $S_5$ as the graph of some smooth function. (I have this gut feeling, but at the moment I can't think of a simpler example to illustrate this)

Comment: Is there any process to determine the points where we can locally describe $S_{5}$ as the graph of a smooth function? Or would it have to be trial and error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot answer that well enough. All I have is a vague recollection of a lecture a few months ago where we saw how badly-behaved the level set of a critical value can be. Also, I do not know of any results which investigate what happens at a critical value (this is certainly a good question, which I had myself but never pursued)